# getting tfs shevleset details from command line

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

Wanted to know if there was a way one could query shelveset details from the command line. I often have need to migrate shelvesets of mine to later branches so as to finally check them in. Problem is when one uses Team Foudation Power Tools (tfpt migrate) command it requires knowing not only the shelveset name but the source branch it was developed / shevled under.  Would be nice to find a way to capitalize on having already provided the "Shevleset Name".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553884/get-tfs-shelveset-file-contents-at-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the [tf.exe Shelvesets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command enough for you ?

Then [tf.exe status /shelveset:Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s5ae285%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you want to display the changes in the shelveset.